# JSON data network communication between c++ and c# project

Tags: c#, c++, json

In one of my project, I meet a problem of network communication between two projects, one is written in C++ (MFC) and another one is in C#.

For my case, the C# project is the server and the C++ project as client. The C++ project needs to send some data to the server (should be serialized class object) via socket, and the server receives the data and de-serializes it.

Currently, the **cpprestsdk** in C++ and **Newtonsoft.Json** in C# are used respectively. But I do not know how to implement this data communication.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: My final solution is that use both the libraries to generate Json strings, and then serialize them to be communicated via socket.

Comment: This kind of questions is not allowed, you need to provide exactly your code, because your question is very broad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, socket client/server communication, i have also compressed, encrypted and converted in hex char (so i have no problem sending.. ex in a html string)